# negation of regular expression for first character alphabet, from second character onwards any character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to form a regular expression for the "Name" text field that should allow

"first character alphabet, from second character on wards any character"

Please help me to create the negation of the regular expression for the above so that if the user is trying to key in first character other than alphabet cannot key in.

I am trying to invoke the code given below but not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Name").keyup(function(){ $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]*$/, "")); })
      });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     Name:
     <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please find the plunker link :

https://plnkr.co/edit/NTzyNpWqEUtgRgVAnHiy?p=preview

Comment: `"first character alphabet, from second character on wards any character"` **what**? Shouldn't it rather be: `"only characters"` ?! It's not clear at all, you're searching for a `Name`... what means to you `"Alphabet character"` and `"Any character"`... ? It's unclear what you mean.

Comment: I want to  accept a name having  "numbers, special characters, alphabets"   from second character onwards , first character should accept only alphabet.  Thank you.

Comment: [`<input name="Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z].*" />`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/b2zh6x7d/)

Comment: @Tushar browser support? IE10, 9...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Pretty good, you can say. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern. Who uses IE 9, 10?

Comment: Sad to say but IE10 holds still 11% of market share, IE9: 5.3%... IE8: 3.2 ... you count ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the '.' before the *

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
$("#Name").keyup(function(){ $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^[^a-zA-Z].*$/, '')); })
```

Edited plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CIXCLzRTVIVXIcjnjWd7